# Look at historical states of ETH accounts older than latest 256 blocks on-chain

Tags: solidity, merkle-patricia-tries

Is it possible to access historical states of Ethereum accounts that are older than 256 latest blocks on-chain?

Does Ethereum client provide any means within its execution context (header, state, etc.) of a transaction to access all the states that exist starting from root?

If, for example, one were to attempt to check/verify several years old state of an Ethereum account's balance on-chain, would that be possible? Apart from supplying the whole merkle tree data from root and onwards to a smart contract, is there another way? (no matter how costly it might be in terms of gas consumption)